# How to unwind a column in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe is like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':["{'c':1}", "{'d':3}", "{'c':5, 'd':6}"]})
```

Expected output:

```
   a    c    d
0  1  1.0  NaN
1  2  NaN  3.0
2  3  5.0  6.0
```

Working solution would be `df['b'].apply(pd.Series)` but this is not working as the b column is string but not dict. I am not defining the column structure, so can't tweak that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) for this and then as you already stated apply pd.Series with a join.

```
import pandas as pd
import ast

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':["{'c':1}", "{'d':3}", "{'c':5, 'd':6}"]})

#convert strings to actual dictionaries
df['b'] = df['b'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

#expand data to seperate columns
out = df.join(df.pop('b').apply(pd.Series))
print(out)
```

```
   a    c    d
0  1  1.0  NaN
1  2  NaN  3.0
2  3  5.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ast.literal_eval and pandas.concat like this:

```
import ast
pd.concat([df.a, df.b.apply(ast.literal_eval).apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What if we do the transformation in parts? Say we have these data:

```
data = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':["{'c':1}", "{'d':3}", "{'c':5, 'd':6}"]}
```

But instead of converting them into a data frame all together, we do it separately. `data['a']` is gonna be an easy part:

```
A = pd.Series(data['a']).rename('a')
```

Now `data['b']`. I like `literal_eval` as a nice and obvious way to handle this. But just for fun, why not to look at this as json records?

```
B = pd.read_json(f"[{','.join(data['b'])}]".replace("'",'"'))
```

And the final touch:

```
df = pd.concat([A, B], axis=1)
```